# Given an array that contains all elements thrice except one. Find the element which occurs once.

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find a special number in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208343/find-a-special-number-in-an-array)

Given an array that contains all elements thrice except one. Find the element which occurs once. Time complexity- O(n). Space complexity- O(1).

Eg. ar[10]={1,2,1,2,5,5,5,7,1,2}.
    ans= 7.

Comment: Have you tried anything? ...and is this homework?

Comment: This has been asked very similarly as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772561/number-which-occurs-only-once-in-the-array

Comment: I have tried but couldn't solve with given complexity.

Comment: @Nick: They are different problems.

Comment: @Nick.Also XOR won't work here.

Comment: @Blender.I have only slutions in mind but they don't follow up complexity.One is to sort it and then check adjacent elemnts. Second is to do Hashing.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5208533/622391

Comment: @Kay i have 1 processor only.

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie -- i think that's exactly what i want!!. thanks. But will it not overflow, if i give inputs in order like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7..., 3,2,1 ?

Comment: Actually, the linked answer may do it. O_o

Comment: That answer is horribly written, though. Can't understand what's going on...

Comment: There is a nice explanation of the answer here
http://shashank7s.blogspot.de/2011/03/wap-for-find-one-elements-which-occurs.html