# How much storage for summation of 1 to 4 billion

Tags: architecture

Inspired by this question ([Find an integer not among four billion given ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7153659/425809)).

How much storage space would it require to store an integer that was the summation of the numbers 1 to 4 billion?

For example, 1+2+3+4+5 = 15.  Summation of 1 to 1 million = 500,000,500,000.

[Here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=141011) is an algorithm that may help

Comment: I can't believe you actually searched the internet for the sum of all numbers from 1 to a million. Use the triangular number identity or even [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+1+to+1000000)

Comment: Umm... That link describes the triangular number formula.  Anyways, the question isn't about the value, but the storage requirements. (and not of 1 to 1 million, but 1 to 4 billion)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you link to describe how to find the n'th [Triangular Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), which is defined as the sum of the n natural numbers from 1 to n.

Substituting 4 billion as n into the function gives 8000000002000000000.

Expressing that as a number of bits can be worked out by taking the base-2 logarithm of the value and rounding up -

ceil(log(8000000002000000000)/log(2)) = 63

So, 63 bits of storage are required.

Answer (score 9):

```
In [12]: import math

In [13]: n=4000000000

In [15]: sumn = n*(n+1)/2

In [16]: sumn
Out[16]: 8000000002000000000L

In [24]: math.log(sumn)/math.log(2)
Out[24]: 62.794705708333197
```

Answer: 63 bits.

Answer (score 5):

One bit is plenty, if you choose an appropriate encoding for integers.

You only need more than **n** bits if there are **more than 2^n** possible values you could potentially need to store.  Here there is only one value that you require to be able to store.

Comment: Are you saying you can store the value 8000000002000000000 in one bit?

Comment: Yes. In fact, there are an infinite number of encodings that allow me to do this.

Comment: _encodings_.  Ok, fair enough. +1