# Find an integer not present in given 4 billion integers

Tags: java, algorithm, bitset, large-data

I came across this question in cracking the coding interview book.

> Question: Given an input file with four billion non-negative integers,
>   provide an algorithm to generate an integer which is not contained in
>   the file. Assume you have 1 GB of memory available for this task.

My question: Why can't we use BitSet instead of Byte[] ? Won't that simplify things ?

Code:

```
 long numberOflnts = ((long) Integer.MAX_VALUE) + I;
 byte[] bitfield = new byte [(int) (numberOflnts / 8)];
 void findOpenNumberQ throws FileNotFoundException {
 Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("file.txt"));
 while (in.hasNextlntQ) {
 int n = in.nextlnt ();
 /* Finds the corresponding number in the bitfield by using
 * the OR operator to set the nth bit of a byte
 * (e.g., 10 would correspond to the 2nd bit of index 2 in
 * the byte array). */
 bitfield [n / 8] |= 1 « (n % 8);
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < bitfield.length; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
 /* Retrieves the individual bits of each byte. When 0 bit
 * is found, finds the corresponding value. */
 if ((bitfield[i] & (1 « j)) == 0) {
 System.out.println (i * 8 + j);
 return;
 }
 }
 }
}
```

Follow up:
What if you have only 10 MB of memory? Assume that all the values are distinct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153659/find-an-integer-not-among-four-billion-given-ones

Comment: This is a problem from "programming pearls" isnt it?

Comment: Why can't we use BitSet instead of Byte[] ?

Comment: @Walt `BitSet` is Java specific. The question is not. You're also missing the point of the question.

Comment: Oh ok. So, I think we can very well use BitSet. What do I do with this question now ? Delete it ?

Comment: With `util.BitSet`, bit indices are limited by 2^31, so it doesn't matter whether a billion is 10^12 or 10^9: assuming `that all the values are distinct`, not all can be used with `util.BitSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does allow for alternative solutions. Java's `BitSet` can work but there are a couple of hidden traps:

- The Java VM will need some memory. So you may run out of memory.
- The `BitSet` is backed by an array. Java arrays use 32bit signed int as indexes, so you effectively have 2^31 entries. Since each is a 64bit long, that is enough.
- When bits are added, the set grows. Eventually, the Java code needs to allocate a new array for the new bits. If you're not careful, you can run out of memory in this step. The fix is to create the array with 2^32 bits from the beginning.