# How to determine if a 2D array contains a specific number?

Tags: arrays

I have a 2D array: `(int[,] sz = new int[52, 5];)` filled with int32s (all of them is between 1 and 90). I need to decide if there is at least one number between 1 and 90, that is not contained in the array.I only need a yes or no answer.

I tried with `Array.Exists`, but it didn't work (I probably didn't use it properly).

I'm looking for the most simple solution (just started recently, I'm far from expert), and I would apreciate a little help :)

Comment: It is useful to say the language you are using.

Comment: Which language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a boolean array of 90 positions, initialized to False.

Then, you go through the 2D array and mark True on the positions of the first array *if* the number is between 1 and 90. Careful: positions on arrays are usually from 0 to 89.

Finally, you can search in the boolean array if it is some False value, indicating that a value does not exists in the 2D array.

The question is a common exercise, similar to:

[Find an integer not among four billion given ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153659/find-an-integer-not-among-four-billion-given-ones)